# Change default outgoing IP adress on latest Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, networking, routing, ip, route

I just set up a second IP adress on my Ubuntu server and now I'm trying to change the default outgoing IP adress to the new one with 
`ip route replace default via <old-ip> src <new-ip>`.

But whenever I restart the networking service, it gets changed to the old IP adress.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, that is because Ubuntu sets the default route dynamically on every startup of the networking service. You can open /etc/network/interfaces and append your command under the interface like this:

```
post-up ip route replace default via <old-ip> src <new-ip>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you are trying to change your ip address?

https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/network-configuration.html

change the settings in /etc/network/interfaces to set the ip address you would like. Just change eth0 to eth1 or whatever interface is.

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 10.0.0.100
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 10.0.0.1
```

Comment: I want to keep both for inbound connections but only the new one for outbound connections.

Comment: Make sure the correct default gateway is set in the `interfaces` file, and remove all other `gateway` directives.